# Comparar condición en WHERE SQL

Tags: sql

Como puedo escribir la sentencia de tal manera que compare dentro del WHERE de la siguiente forma: Si `@EntSalAmbas = 'E'` que compare por  `TBLAccesos.Entrada_Salida = 1` y si por el contrario `@EntSalAmbas = 'S'` que compare por `TBLAccesos.Entrada_Salida = 0`

```
WHERE (@EntSalAmbas = 'E' TBLAccesos.Entrada_Salida = 1) 
    OR (@EntSalAmbas = 'S' TBLAccesos.Entrada_Salida = 0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una posibilidad sería escribirlo así:

```
WHERE (@EntSalAmbas = 'E' AND TBLAccesos.Entrada_Salida = 1)
   OR (@EntSalAmbas = 'S' AND TBLAccesos.Entrada_Salida = 0)
```

De esa forma, cuando `@EntSalAmbas = 'E'` solo la primer parte de la condición puede ser verdadera, y solo cuando `TBLAccesos.Entrada_Salida = 1`. Y el razonamiento inverso cuando vale `'S'`...

Answer (score 2):

Prueba esto:

```
Update nombretabla
SET TBLAccesos.Entrada_Salida = Case when @EntSalAmbas = 'E' then 1
    when @EntSalAmbas= 'S' then 0
END
```

Comment: ¿Por qué? Sería bueno añadir explicaciones para que la respuesta sea más útil. Date una vuelta por [answer] y el [tour].

Comment: Gracias por la información tío me salvaste la vida en La Oficina